# How to add static html markup to a CiviCRM form

Tags: php, civicrm, quickform

I have CiviCRM 4.4.6 + Drupal 7 and i alter one of CiviCRM's forms.

Inside `hook_civicrm_buildForm()`, i try to:

```
form->addElement('html', 'statichtml', '<div>aa</div>');
$template =& CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton();
$bhfe = $template->get_template_vars('beginHookFormElements');
if (!$bhfe) {
  $bhfe = array();
}
$bhfe[] = 'statichtml';
$form->assign('beginHookFormElements', $bhfe);
```

If i use it with 'text' element type, it works correctly. This way nothing is rendered, but an empty additional `tr` is added.
How to use this type of element correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pear.php.net/manual/hu/package.html.html-quickform.intro-elements.php
Here is the explanation.
The element type should be `static`, not `html` and the above code starts to work.